# How to append /META-INF/BenchmarkList to jmh task to fix "ERROR: Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList"

Tags: java, performance, gradle, build.gradle, jmh

I'm new to micro bench-marking in general. When I execute the JMH task in my project I get "ERROR: Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList", I believe is created by jmh-generator-annprocess. I am using **Gradle** and I am trying to figure out if jmh-generator-annprocess is even working? Will it work properly for Gradle or do I need to use the Maven plugin or something?

`https://github.com/coderrick/JMH-Studies.git` in case you want to `git clone` my project and run it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There was a couple of issues

1. `JMHSample_02_BenchmarkModes` class was in incorrectly named java class
2. build.gradle was missing `apply plugin: "me.champeau.gradle.jmh"` declaration
3. In `jmhJar` section `Main-Class` manifest entry was overridden (which is unnecessary)

I've made a [PR](https://github.com/coderrick/JMH-Studies/pull/1) with above fixes. After applying it you can run performance tests using

```
java -jar build/libs/JMH-Studies-jmh.jar
```